# Scanning numbers from a file line to line and stopping at some point (C)

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, scanf

I have a file (input.dat) with several lines, each of which has 4 numbers. I want to write a script in C that reads the numbers on line 10, which I will save as var_i_10 (with i=1,2,3,4). Then, I want it to check line by line until the 2nd number is 5% lower than var_2_10. At that point, I want the program to write down the line where it has stopped on another file (output.dat).

This is what I've come up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
    
    FILE *Fdata;  //The file with the data
    FILE *Foutput;  //The file I want to write the final result
    float *var_1, *var_2, *var_3, *var_4, *var_1_10, *var_2_10, *var_3_10, *var_4_10; //The variables in input.dat
    int i; //The line number
   
    Fdata=fopen("input.dat","r");
    Foutput = fopen("output.dat","w+");
    
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        
        fscanf(Fdata,"%f %f %f %f \n", var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4); //skip the first 50 lines
        
    }
    
    fscanf(Fdata, "%f %f %f %f \n", var_1_10, var_2_10, var_3_10, var_4_10); //save the numbers on line 10
    
    i = 10;
    
    
    while ((var_2_10 - var_2)<0.05*(*var_2_10)){ 
        
        fscanf(Fdata,"%f %f %f %f \n", var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4); //keep reading until var_2 is 5% lower than var_2_10
        
        i++;
        
    }
    
    fprintf(Foutput, "%d \n", i); //print the number o the last line read
    fclose(Foutput);
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Now, the script compiles, but when I try to execute it, it gives me the "segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I have almost no knowledge of C, so there are probably a lot of mistakes in my code.

The input.dat file looks like this:

```
1.8125 0.944824 7.43362e-05 7.88432e-06
1.74121 0.918457 4.73094e-05 0.000127544
1.69922 0.897949 6.00231e-05 2.91268e-05
1.7334 0.905762 0.000317385 7.81227e-05
1.70898 0.899902 0.000243394 2.10955e-05
1.72559 0.903809 9.5074e-05 0.000149768
1.71387 0.899414 0.000166243 0.000185066
1.68359 0.89209 0.00018385 0.000303927
1.68359 0.88623 0.000219556 0.000178714
1.70508 0.894531 0.000488326 0.000411066
1.69336 0.880859 0.000139567 0.000568174
1.70605 0.89209 0.000196065 0.000167238
1.69043 0.882324 5.66663e-05 0.00017306
1.67578 0.881836 0.00014178 0.000137113
1.67969 0.876465 0.000261803 2.60709e-05
1.67773 0.879883 0.000250439 8.21055e-05
1.71191 0.879395 0.000311615 0.000118544
1.68652 0.879883 0.00023477 0.000101067
1.68262 0.890625 0.000310484 8.81731e-05
1.70898 0.890137 0.000591565 3.71699e-05
1.70312 0.89502 0.000248289 7.57763e-05
1.71875 0.903809 0.000555975 4.18079e-05
1.71289 0.901367 0.000265478 3.96961e-05
1.69434 0.892578 5.50881e-05 0.00085942
1.68945 0.880371 0.000153156 0.0011145
1.66504 0.868164 0.000155594 0.000752835
1.65039 0.853027 0.000255484 0.00133279
1.6748 0.862793 0.000207765 0.00148763
1.66406 0.850586 0.00043458 0.00064662
1.63086 0.84082 0.00124341 0.000331652
1.66113 0.848145 0.00141408 0.00108942
1.64746 0.845215 0.000985863 0.000169982
1.65039 0.855957 0.000606564 0.000577116
1.65527 0.853027 0.000982811 0.000660586
1.63086 0.841309 0.000670502 0.00120878
1.64746 0.84668 0.000579282 0.000597114
1.67871 0.850586 0.000324774 0.00139627
1.63574 0.82959 0.000331599 0.00224275
1.61719 0.828125 0.000564358 0.00185258
1.66504 0.845215 0.000896463 0.00230424
1.64062 0.832031 0.000774724 0.00195404
1.62793 0.835449 0.000624469 0.00127606
```

Comment: Hint: When `fscanf(Fdata,"%f %f %f %f \n", var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4);` is called, what is the value of  the pointer `var_1` passed to the function?

Comment: From what I understand, the value of var_1 is the adress to the first number of the line, right?

Comment: Marcosko, Not quite.  `var_1` value passed **into** `scanf()` is something determined **before** the function call.  Posted code passed in garbage and the results was seg-fault.

Comment: I understand. So I have to pass the adress of my variable to `scanf()` rather than passing a random pointer, right?

Comment: Marcosko, Yas, as the checked answer suggests, pass in the address of  a known `float` so `scanf()` knows where to store its input.  BTW, check the return value of `scanf()` to assess success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chux provided you with a clue in his comment above.

You correctly seem to realize that - for integer placeholders - `fscanf()` expects a pointer to an integer (i.e. its address).

The problem is that the pointers you pass are 'pointing' to random addresses in memory.

So `fscanf()` tries to de-reference invalid pointers when parsing.
This would cause the segmentation fault you refer to.

Instead of

```
float *var_1, *var_2, *var_3, *var_4; // etc..
```

use

```
float var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4; // etc.
```

and in your calls to `fscanf()` pass the *address* of these variables (not the variables themselves). E.g., instead of

```
fscanf(Fdata,"%f %f %f %f \n", var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4);
```

use

```
fscanf(Fdata,"%f %f %f %f \n", &var_1, &var_2, &var_3, &var_4);
```

You will need to make this change for all of your `fscanf()` calls.

There is one more issue with your program.
Once you declare `var_1`, `var_2`, *etc.* as *floats* rather than *pointers to floats*, you will need to change one other line in your code - involving a pointer dereference.
Since `var_2_10` will no longer be a pointer, it will not make sense to de-reference it.

You might be able to resolve that yourself - the culprit line is reasonably obvious.

As an aside, variables with local scope - if not explicitly initialized - will contain random values. So your variables `var_1`, `var_2`, *etc.* will be pointing to random addresses.

Comment: That's it, thank you very much. The code works perfectly now, and I actually learned something about pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `fscanf()`. you should use  `fscanf(Fdata,"%f %f %f %f \n", &var_1, &var_2, &var_3, &var_4);`. If you are working with a file always check whether the file is loaded or not. Below there is code that helps you to check for loaded file and then do your task.[Click here to get code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSOXR.png)